# Replacing a dual N-channel MOSFET with another with different heat dissipation pads assignment

Tags: mosfet

Trying to replace the FDMD82100 with an FDMS8090 used in a half-bridge circuit.

The 82100 has S1 connected to D2 and the heat dissipation pads connected to D1 and S2.

The 8090 has dual N-MOS with heat dissipation pads connected to D1 ad D2.

Is this going to be a problem?

Edit: actual circuit pic is added.

Comment: Welcome! You need to re-layout your board. How does your cooling situation look?

Comment: Thank you winny. The layouter has no problem with that. The cooling is done through these pads and also partially by connecting S2 to ground through multiple connection points.

Answer (score 2):

Your main focus should be on comparing how the new device might perform in your target circuit and not in comparing data sheets. For instance, if your gate drivers are a tad weak (but OK for the [82100](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/149/FDMD82100-278426.pdf)) then, they may not be able to drive the higher gate-source capacitance of the [8090](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/fdms8090-d.pdf) (almost twice as much as the 82100).

The all-round larger capacitance of the 8090 might be problematic in other areas too so, focus on your target design and work out whether you need to improve the gate drivers to overcome these extra problems.

Only you can do this. There may be other areas where the "stronger" 8090 might cause your circuit problems but that would be guesswork on my part.

Making data sheet comparisons without referring to the target schematic is never a good idea. Always choose an alternative part as if you were designing it into the circuit from scratch. So, if you are not equipped to do that task then, you must use a person capable of circuit design.

Comment: Thank you, Andy aka. Am using the MIC4606-2 full-bridge driver. Am not sure how to test for compatibility and if the driver is able to properly switch the two MOSFETs (four if you consider the other half-bridge).

Comment: Neither am I unfortunately due to complete lack of schematics. BTW, that isn't an invite for you to post complete schematics. What my answer is telling you is that a data sheet comparison is of no use without analysing every aspect the device and prospective device in the target circuit. It's basically something that a circuit designer should do so, if you are not equipped to do that then you must use a person capable of circuit design to do this task.

Comment: just posted the schematic in case it can help further.

Comment: It's not going to help without knowing (at least as a minimum) the code that drives the PWM lines and the full characteristics of the loads and the power supply ranges. Do you see that this is best done within your own area and not here. Nobody is going to do this work for you reliably on-line and, even if they did, how would you know that their analyses were correct without a 2nd opinion. You need to do this yourself.

Comment: I see your point. Furthermore, I discussed the issue with a more experienced engineer than myself and after viewing the whole schematic It was ok'd as long as the MOSFET driver is good for the new dual n-channel mos. So the pads issue is no more a concern.  Anyway, it's good to learnthat it's not a one-dimensional issue when it comes to choosing an alternative part.

Comment: @Elektroneu please [take the 2 minute tour](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour) to understand why folk give free advice on this site. Always choose an alternative part as if you were designing from scratch. Data sheet comparisons are not sufficient to be able to swap parts unless everything absolutely matches but, you then still need to verify that your original design is not operating the device beyond some part of the original data sheet.

Comment: @Elektroneu [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)